# List taxonomy terms plus their latest post ordered by post date

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms, order, date-time

I have the following code:

```php
$custom_terms = get_terms('columna');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'=>1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'columna',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order'   => 'DESC',
                'suppress_filters' => true,
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,

            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);

     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h4>'.$custom_term->name.'</h4>';
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>'.get_the_date().'<br>';
        endwhile;
     }
}
```

It works, but it gets me something like this:

```
* term 1
 * post 1 - 2019-12-01
* term 2
 * post 2 - 2020-01-01
```

What I'd need is that the term with the most recent post, goes first in the list:

```
* term 2
 * post 2 - 2020-01-01
* term 1
 * post 1 - 2019-12-01
```

Comment: Why do you call `wp_reset_query`? That function should only be used to cleanup after a `query_posts` call. As for the terms, you need to know how recent the post is before you can order the terms. There's no way to tell `get_terms` to sort them that way, you'd have to do the sorting yourself manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are performing the query by term, and displaying results instantly. What you need is to gather the results of each query, sort them and then display separately.

**Make sure to read code comments.**

```php
/* $custom_terms = get_terms('columna'); - this approach is depreciated */
$custom_terms = get_terms( array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'columna' 
) );


// store each posts in this array along with the term information
$sorted_posts = array();

foreach ( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'columna',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug
            )
        )
     );

     $posts = get_posts( $args );

     if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            // storing term, post & data as an array item
            $sorted_posts[] = array(
                'term' => $custom_term,
                'post' => $post,
                'date' => $post->post_date
            );
        }
    }
}

/* 
 * now we will sort $sorted_posts to be displayed by date descending. 
 * note: it's compltely fine if you query more than one post from each term.
 */
uasort( $sorted_posts, function( $a, $b ){
    if ( $a['date'] == $b['date'] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a['date'] > $b['date'] ) ? -1 : 1;
});


/*
 * $sorted_posts contains all of our posts in order. 
 * now we will group posts by same term
*/

$terms_posts = array();
foreach ( $sorted_posts as $sorted_post ) {
    if ( ! isset( $terms_posts[ $sorted_post['term']->term_id ] ) ) {
        $terms_posts[ $sorted_post['term']->term_id ] = array(
            'term' => $sorted_post['term'],
            'posts' => array()
        );
    }

    $terms_posts[ $sorted_post['term']->term_id ]['posts'][] = $sorted_post['post'];
}

// just clearing array keys to be incremental. not needed, just to be organized.
$terms_posts = array_values( $terms_posts );


// make the $post variable global so that we can use setup_postdata function.
global $post;

foreach ( $terms_posts as $term_posts ) {
    echo '<h4>'. $term_posts['term']->name.'</h4>';
    foreach ( $term_posts['posts'] as $post ) {

        // following function has made our post object global. it makes sure get_permalink, get_title etc function refers to the current post in loop.
        setup_postdata( $post );

        echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a><br>'. get_the_date() .'<br>';
    }
}

// as we had modified the global post object, we have to restore it.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems the approach is correct as the order of the terms is now right. However, it is not displaying any post now, only the list of terms.

Comment: @JoaquínNavarro, there was a mistake on `foreach ( $term_posts['post'] as $post )` line. It should be `foreach ( $term_posts['posts'] as $post )`. I have updated the code, you can try.

Comment: Brilliant! Now it works perfectly. Again, thanks so much :)

Comment: Hello, is it possible to use this with pagination?

Comment: @Darko Where would you use the pagination, on posts or terms ? Better if you search for other answers for your concern or post it as a question.

Comment: @Shazzad on terms if possible