# Custom Taxonomy terms with latest post ordered by date pagination issue

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination, terms, order

I'm using the similar code from this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/363817/list-taxonomy-terms-plus-their-latest-post-ordered-by-post-date), order terms by post date works only if I display all the terms on the page, example `terms_to_display = 99999`, but if I set it to 6 or for example, the complete loop order gets messed up, it's not continuing on the next pages, it starts again from the newest post again ( minus offset of 6 ) and displays the next 6 posts by date, resulting with having newer posts on the second,third... pages than on the first.

```
    $taxonomy = 'ctc_sermon_series'; //taxonomy name
    $terms_to_display = 6; //number of series to display per page
    $page         = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $totalterms   = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => TRUE ) ); 
    $totalpages   = ceil( $totalterms / $number );
    $posts_per_term = 1; // number of posts per term to display

    $term_count = get_terms( array (
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'fields'   => 'count',
     ) );

    // find out the number of pages to use in pagination
    $max_num_pages = ceil( $term_count / $terms_to_display );

    // get the page number from URL query
    $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );

    // calculate the offset, if there is one.
    $offset = 0; // initial
    // or changed the if not the first (0)
    if( ! 0 == $current_page) {
        $offset = ( $terms_to_display * $current_page ) - $terms_to_display;
    }


    $terms = get_terms ( array (
        'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy, 
        'hide_empty'    => true,
        'number'        => $terms_to_display,
        'offset'        => $offset,
        ) 
    );
    $sermons_items = [];

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $args = array (
            'post_type'         => 'ctc_sermon',
            'posts_per_page'    =>  $posts_per_term,
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array (
             array (
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => array( $term->term_id )
                ),
             ),
          );

        $sermons_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // ignore terms with not enough posts
        if ( $sermons_query->post_count < $posts_per_term ) {
            continue;
        }

        $sermons_posts = $sermons_query->get_posts();

        // get date of newest post in this term
        $newest_post_date = get_the_date( "U", $sermons_posts[0]->ID );

        $sermons_items[$newest_post_date] = array(
            'term' => $term,
            'sermons' => $sermons_posts,
        );
    }

    krsort( $sermons_items ); // sort descending by keys

    $sermons_items = array_slice( $sermons_items, 0, $terms_to_display );


    global $post;

    echo '<section class="grid-posts">';

    foreach ( $sermons_items as $item ) {

        echo '<div class="col-md-6 no-padding grid-post">'; 

        foreach ( $item['sermons'] as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

            <div class="grid-post-content">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/sermon-series/' ) ).$item['term']->slug; ?>">
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php echo $item['term']->name; ?></h2>
                </a>
                <?php
                    echo get_the_title().'</br>';
                    echo get_the_date(); 
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php
        }

        echo '</div>';  

    }

    echo '</section>';


    echo paginate_links( array (
        'total'   => $max_num_pages,
        'current' => $current_page,
    ) );
```

Comment: what you are doing is asking to show only 6 posts maximum, will not show more.

Comment: please be more especific in what is your goal, is it to show 6 posts per page?

Comment: It's a problem with pagination and sorting, for example because of foreach, it sorts the first 6 posts from newest to oldest on the fist page, but on the second page it starts sorting by date again.
example:
Page 1:
  - post 1    01.20.2022 ( newest of the first 6 )
  - post 2    01.20.2017 ( oldest of the first 6 ) 
Page 2:
 - post 7     01.19.2022 ( newest of the second 6 )
 - post 12   01.19.2017 ( oldest of the second 6 )

Comment: For all I understand, when the loop starts, its like there is already a variable with all the posts, so starting the loop again will just show the same result. I had update the answer bellow, for me it works, try it out

Answer (score 0):

to change the number of posts per page you can do it in the wp dashboard
like in this [picture](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/changenumberofpostsonblogpagewp.png)

This function on functions.php works for me

```php
function tcPostsPerPage( $query ) {
  if (is_home()){$query->set('posts_per_page', 6);}
  if (is_archive()){$query->set('posts_per_page', 6);}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tcPostsPerPage' );
```

the two 6 is limiting to 6 per page, if this doest work for you, its a question of changing the is_archive() to something like is_page('yourpage')

also if it works you can remove the 'posts_per_page' of your array, and the variable attached.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but this is a separate template for custom post types an custom taxonomy.

Comment: had edit the answer and put a function that for me it works, but since you have a specific page, you need to test it and if not works change the if check to your page

Comment: the 'posts_per_page' should be it, but it is not, and seems that everytime you make a loop  on a new page everything returns to default, thats why there is this indepent function for you functions.php